# how to include the header view into all other view in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

my controller is

```
function loginProcess()
 {
    $this->db->select('moduleId');
    $this->db->from('roleaccess');
    $this->db->where('userId',$session_data['userId']);
    $query=$this->db->get();
    $access=$query->row_array();
    $variable=implode(",",$access);
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT moduleName,moduleUrl FROM module where    moduleId in($variable)");
    $resultdata['results'] = $query->result_array();
    $responce=$tst+$resultdata;
   $this->load->view('admin/users1',$responce);
}
function user()
{

    //set table id in table open tag
    $tmpl = array ( 'table_open'  => '<table id="big_table" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" class="mytable" style="border-collapse: collapse; ">' );
    $this->table->set_template($tmpl); 
    $this->table->set_heading('Id','Email','UserName','View','Delete');
    $this->load->view('subscriber_view');

}
```

In my view subscriber_view i include the users1 view as follows

```
<?php 
  include("admin/users1.php");
 ?>
```

but it showing the undefined variable results error.how to i include include("admin/users1.php") in all other views.please help me

Answer (score 0):

```
function user()
{

    //set table id in table open tag
    $tmpl = array ( 'table_open'  => '<table id="big_table" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" class="mytable" style="border-collapse: collapse; ">' );
    $this->table->set_template($tmpl); 
    $this->table->set_heading('Id','Email','UserName','View','Delete');
     $this->loginProcess();
    $this->load->view('subscriber_view');

}
```

check this out ... you can add previous controller which is calling the header with the data from database , and it will work on this controller also  :)

Answer (score 0):

you can include files as

```
function loginProcess()
{
  $this->db->select('moduleId');
  $this->db->from('roleaccess');
  $this->db->where('userId',$session_data['userId']);
  $query=$this->db->get();
  $access=$query->row_array();
  $variable=implode(",",$access);
  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT moduleName,moduleUrl FROM module where    moduleId in($variable)");
  $resultdata['results'] = $query->result_array();
  $responce=$tst+$resultdata;
  // loading header before page 
  $this->load->view('admin/header');
  $this->load->view('admin/users1',$responce);
}
function user()
{
  //set table id in table open tag
  $tmpl = array ( 'table_open'  => '<table id="big_table" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" class="mytable" style="border-collapse: collapse; ">' );
 $this->table->set_template($tmpl); 
 $this->table->set_heading('Id','Email','UserName','View','Delete');
 //header
 $this->load->view('header');
 $this->load->view('subscriber_view');
}
```

or at the top of your all view files write following code

```
<?php 
     $this->load->view('header');
?>
```